# Send leads to particular campaign in Marketo?

Tags: rest, marketo

I working on Marketo REST API for the first time. I want to upload multiple leads to a particular campaign. How can we do this? What is the flow of the process so that I can send my leads to a particular campaign on Marketo?
Please help me I'm stuck,I go through documentation but I didn't get any API .

Comment: Hello @jack-ma, kindly go through the Marketo developer  api documentation thoroughly and then come back and show efforts you have made.

Comment: I already read the entire document but not found any help that's why I'm asking for help@kplus,If you know please help me.Thankx in advance.

Comment: Have you seen this ? https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/bulk-import/